# How to get ID of a group or page using php from facebook url?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am looking to get solution for a single and small task. I want to know how to get ID of facebook fanpage,group and user profile id using PHP.

I have tried many things but unfortunately  i am unable to get solution.

For example how to get ID from below link

FanPage = https://facebook.com/pepsi
Group = https://www.facebook.com/groups/TeespringNews/
Same for profile

```
<?php
 $id= $_GET['group-id'];
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tested ans for graph api 2.8
First get the app access token through graph api login

Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK v5.

```
    require( __DIR__.'/path-to-sdk/autoload.php' );

`$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret'            => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);`

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
       //There was an error communicating with Graph
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
      // User authenticated your app!
      $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
      echo 'Successfull!';
      exit;
    } elseif ($helper->getError()) {
      // The user denied the request
      var_dump($helper->getError());
      exit;
    }


$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/testpage/';

if ($url != ''){

        $arg = str_replace(
                array('http://','https://','www.','facebook.com/','/'),
                '',
                $url
        );
}

    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/{$arg}?access_token=".$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
      $content = curl_exec($ch);
      $content = json_decode($content);
      var_dump($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Graph API to get data from Facebook, scraping is not allowed.

For example:

```
$pageData = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/pepsi');
```

Although, i suggest using CURL instead of file_get_contents. And you should always create an App and use an Access Token whenever you access the Graph API. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs